# angularjs ui.router activestate with dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create my menu which have a dropdown for multiple link in the application.

i want it to be "active" while one of the link below is active.

i got the link in my dropdown to be active and i got the dropdown to be active but i never get both of them working together... only one is working...

here is the code, if anyone can point me where i'm doing something wrong!

```
<li class="dropdown" ui-sref-active-eq="active">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Main
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ui-sref-active="active">
            <a ui-sref="Debut1">
                Items
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

EDIT

Here is a plunkr that show the problem 
https://plnkr.co/edit/Ffe9FLz4TuihkVjby6RU

ANSWER

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router'
]);

app.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        var accueil = {
            name: 'accueil',
            url: '/Accueil',
            templateUrl: '/app/views/accueil/accueil.html'
        }

        var debutant = {
            name: 'debut',
            url: '/Debut',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: '/app/views/debut/debut.html'
        }

        var debutant1 = {
            name: 'debut.one',
            url: '/One',
            parent: debutant,
            templateUrl: '/app/views/debut/debut1.html'
        }

        var debutant2 = {
            name: 'debut.two',
            url: '/Two',
            parent: debutant,
            templateUrl: '/app/views/debut/debut2.html'
        }

        $stateProvider.state(accueil);
        $stateProvider.state(debutant);
        $stateProvider.state(debutant1);
        $stateProvider.state(debutant2);
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Accueil');
    }
]);
```

index.html

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ui-sref-active="active">
            <a ui-sref="accueil">
                Accueil
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown" ui-sref="debut" ui-sref-active="active">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Début 
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li ui-sref-active="active">
                    <a ui-sref="debut.one">
                        Début 1
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li ui-sref-active="active">
                    <a ui-sref="debut.two">
                        Début 2
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

debut.html

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

Comment: No one know how to make  ui-sref-active-eq work with ui-sref-active ? i must not be the first one to do the Active on Nav li and the li in the dropdown

Comment: Which version of ui-router are you using? according to version 0.2.13:

ui-sref-active="active" now sets the 'active' class when the current state is the ui-sref's state or any child

ui-sref-active-eq="active" behaves as the previous iterations of ui-sref-active, and only sets the class for the exact state

Comment: i'm using "0.3.2"

Comment: so how can i make both parent to active ?

Comment: What about switching your directives: I mean where you have ui-sref-active-eq use the other one ui-sref-active. And vice versa.

Comment: it put the li in the dropdown active but not the li in the nav is not active

Comment: Could you provide a complete plunkr, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Did you see the problem in the plunkr?

Comment: I got you now. You could do something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/hXBrmYLh8NXXFFNhq5rn?p=preview
Using the ng-class directive.

Comment: i though there was a directive for this in ui-router but i will take your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found few days later the real solution to my problem.

Because i was having console error with the solution of @John Spiteri.

switched my view to

```
<li class="dropdown" ui-sref-active="{'active': 'debut.**'}">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Début
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ui-sref-active="active">
            <a ui-sref="debut.one">
                Début 1
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

So the solution is this part:

ui-sref-active="{'active': 'debut.**'}"

where the .** match any child of the parent!

Answer (score 0):

ui-sref-active will stay active for all child routes... the issue is with your implementation of UI-Router.

When I think logically about route chaining, it goes something like this.

'/' = 'app.inventory' //abstract: true - possibly sharing resolve or data
'/inventory/' = 'app.inventory.list'
'/inventory/shoes/' = 'app.inventory.shoes'

I had to change my approach (and thinking) to make ui-sref-active work.

Make the start (debutant) route the parent, then swap out the only partial with a child.

You will notice that the 'accueil' state is staying active...

```
    $stateProvider
      .state('accueil', {
        url: '/accueil',
        views: {
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: './accueil.html'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('accueil.debutant', {
        url: '/debutant',
        views: {
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: './debut.html'
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/8u3RhHRiPdhdF1lhWbeM?p=preview

Also, added a version for the child being active also...

https://plnkr.co/edit/dXexFM38IUF3uaBGPovL?p=preview

Comment: in my plunker i'm showing a dropdown not a simple nav menu, take time to understand my plunkr we are not doing the same thing

Comment: @Vince here is the one step further... I am getting the idea across that is holding you back. You need to take the ball from there...  https://plnkr.co/edit/PWbS4RwcRXlIo30npJRB?p=preview

Comment: your example show the same problem as i have in my initial post

Comment: the dropdown is not active when u select on one his child

Comment: @Vince I understand what you mean now... for the dropdown to activate, the user needs to click the second link, so the same logic applies... https://plnkr.co/edit/iqdRFx47Nj5khmueU06H?p=preview

Comment: @Vince... also I use the highest element possible for anchors or directives (eg... li instead of the anchor that is inside) and putting ui-sref and ui-sref-active in the same element (if possible).

Comment: It's perfect and as i want! :D thx a lot for this, i changed the app.js to my fit but it's working :) i will edit my initial post to show the answer !